# NodeJS/MongoDB: Perform Slice operation on an array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am having a tough time trying to execute a slice on an array
I have a collection called comments, each document has an array field, i want to access it and apply slice for paging purpose please help !! tried `monk` and `mongodb` no good

Example:

```
 {  
   _id:xyz,
   msgs:[{.....},{.....},{.....}]
 }


database.collection("comments")
  .find({"_id": id},{ "msgs": { "$slice": [2,5] } })
  .toArray( function(err, result){
        //implementation
   });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For `mongodb` Driver:**

Instead of

```
.find({"_id": id},{ "msgs": { "$slice": [2,5] } })
```

Use

```
.find({"_id": id}).project({ "msgs": { "$slice": [2,5] } })
```

As given [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) the `$slice` operator is of **Projection** type.
The `mongodb` driver for **NodeJS** needs call to an extra `.project` function to project selective fields as well as to use projection operators.

Answer (score 0):

From the node-js mongo driver [docs](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/CHANGES_3.0.0.md#find):

2.x syntax:

```
const cursor = coll.find({ a: 42 }, { someField: 1 });
```

3.x syntax:

```
const cursor = coll.find({ a: 42 }).project({ someField: 1 });

/* OR */

`const cursor = coll.find({ a: 42 }, { projection: { someField: 1 } });`
```

Basically node-js mongo driver version upgrade from 2.x to 3.x had several "breaking" changes including the projection in a query.